# SuiteCRM Scheduler Task Returns 301

Tags: scheduler, suitecrm

I feel like this is a very simple problem with a very simple solution, but I can't find what I might have missed.

I have a Scheduler task in SuiteCRM. It thinks it is firing successfully, but the work isn't done, and the log contains a 301 error redirecting the Scheduler task to the login page. If I access the function myself while logged in at the exact address Scheduler is trying to access, it fires just fine.

Is there a setting I might have missed that isn't allowing Scheduler tasks to run without some sort of authentication? Did I miss some sort of authentication on my function that needs to run?

Comment: Is the address the scheduler is trying to access an Entry Point?

Comment: Yes, but I had the Entry Point set up incorrectly. I was trying to access a controller action, and it was 301'ing me. Your comment prompted me to try breaking it out into its own php, and that worked as an entry point just fine.